# Generic method to act on all class

Tags: ios, swift

I have classes as

```
class Citizen{

    var name:String
    var age:Int
    var lawPrevilige = 0

    init(name:String,age:Int){

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

class Politician{

    var name:String
    var age:Int
    var lawPrevilige = 1

    init(name:String,age:Int){

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

}
```

And a class to manipulate those

```
class PoliceDept{

    var departMentName = "InterPol"
    var departMentAddress:String = "Earth"

    //this method should be able to access object of any class with the same properties.
    func investigateAnyOne(person:AnyObject){


        if let p = person as? Citizen{

            print(p.name)


        }else if let po =  person as? Politician{

            print(po.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the question is if I have a class `Disabled People`, `UnderAge People` etc with the exact properties name and age..So  how can i make method `investigateAnyOne` of Police Dept act on AnyObject without the TypeCasting. Is that possible?

Downcasting to every types of object for 10-12 classes makes code messy..Should i create multiple if else statement to check the type of class or any other way conforming to protocol.

The question is  what should i do if there are many other types of people who i want to investiaget..

Comment: Generally: common superclass `Person` or a protocol. – But: Are "Politician" and "Disabled People" disjoint categories?

Comment: Yes they are not dependent to each other for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `Protocol` and define all the properties there and Conform to the Common `Protocol` in all the classes. so you wouldn't need to check multiple cases in `investigateAnyOne`.

```
protocol Common {
var name:String {get set}
var age:Int {get set}
 var lawPrevilige:Int {get set}

}

class Politician: Common{

 var name:String
 var age:Int
 var lawPrevilige = 1

 init(name:String,age:Int){

 self.name = name
 self.age = age
 }

}

class PoliceDept{

 var departMentName = "InterPol"
 var departMentAddress:String = "Earth"


 func investigateAnyOne(person: Common){
   self.departMentName = person.name
  }
}
```

create an object of `Politician` and pass it in  `investigateAnyOne` method.

```
let politician = Politician(name: "demo", age: 10)
let policeDept = PoliceDept()
 policeDept.investigateAnyOne(politician)
```

Comment: Does this work if i have two classes subclassed from UIKit class..e.g. UITableViewCell? with common outlets

Comment: it will only work when your classes will conform to the Common protocol. and you can't use outlet using creating yourclass object only you can use the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enumeration to define the various roles of a person and simply assign it as a property to the general Person structure like this.

```
enum Priviledge {
  case citizen
  case politician
  case underage
}

struct Person {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
  let priviledge: Priviledge

  init(name: String, age: Int, priviledge: Priviledge) {
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.priviledge = priviledge
  }
}

struct PoliceDept {
  ...
  func investigateAnyOne(person: Person) {
    switch (person.priviledge) {
    case .citizen:
      print("\(person.name) is a citizen")
    case .politician:
      print("\(person.name) is a politician")
    case .underage:
      print("\(person.name) is a child")
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `class` instead of `struct` in this code, but I am a recovering OOP-aholic.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `Person` to define the role enumeration and your structure containing `name` and `age` as an associated value.

```
struct Details {
  let name: String
  let age: Int

  init(name: String, age: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  }
}

enum Person {
  case citizen(Details)
  case politician(Details)
  case underage(Details)
}

struct PoliceDept {
  ...
  func investigateAnyOne(person: Person) {
    switch (person) {
    case .citizen(let details):
      print("\(details.name) is a citizen")
    case .politician(let details):
      print("\(details.name) is a politician")
    case .underage(let details):
      print("\(details.name) is a child")
    }
  }
}
```